# Download parquet file from ADL Gen2 using powershell

Tags: azure, parquet, azure-powershell

I am using below powershell command to download TSV file from ADL to local system and it works absolutely fine

```html
#this appid has access to ADL
[string] $AppID  = "bbb88818-aaaa-44fb-q2345678901y" 
 [string] $TenantId  = "ttt88888-xxxx-yyyy-q2345678901y"
 [string] $SubscriptionName  = "Sub Sample"
 [string] $AzureDataLakeAccountName  = "sample.blob.core.windows.net"

 [string] $AzureDataLakeSrcFilePath  = "/accounts/sample/test.tsv"
 [string] $LocalTargetFilePathName  = "D:\MoveToModern"


Write-Host "AppID = " $AppID
Write-Host "TenantId = " $TenantId
Write-Host "SubscriptionName = " $SubscriptionName
Write-Host "AzureDataLakeAccountName = " AzureDataLakeAccountName
Write-Host "AzureDataLakeSrcFilePath = " $AzureDataLakeSrcFilePath
Write-Host "LocalTargetFilePathName = " $LocalTargetFilePathName



#this is the access key of the appid
$AccessKeyValue = "1234567=u-r.testabcdefaORYsw5AN5"

$azurePassword    = ConvertTo-SecureString $AccessKeyValue -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred           = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AppID, $azurePassword)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $TenantId

Get-AzureRmSubscription

Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName  | Set-AzureRmContext
Export-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName $AzureDataLakeAccountName -Path $AzureDataLakeSrcFilePath  -Destination $LocalTargetFilePathName -Force
```

But when I replace sourcefile path with value **/accounts/sample/test-V4.parquet**, I get below error:

*ADLSException: Error in getting metadata for path /accounts/Partner/Non-PII/Account/Account-V4.parquet.
Operation: GETFILESTATUS failed with HttpStatus:Forbidden  Error: Unexpected error in JSON parsing of the error stream. Content-Type of error response: application/xml.
ExceptionType: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException ExceptionMessage: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. 
`AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:de2e4b16-001e-002e-625f-c92785000000*

[image]

Can you please let me know how can I download parquet file from ADL Gen2 using powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provide, you do not have enough permissions to do that. So you get **Forbidden** error. If you want to download a file from Azure data lake store with a service principal, we need to grant the security principal read access to the file and give the security principal Execute permissions to the container and each folder in the hierarchy of folders that lead to the file.

For example
[image]

Please check it and set the right ACL. Regarding how to do that, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory#step-3-assign-the-azure-ad-application-to-the-azure-data-lake-storage-gen1-account-file-or-folder)

---

If you want to download files from Azure Data Lake Gen2, I suggest you use PowerShell module `Az.Storage`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell)

For example

1. Configure ACL for the service principal.

If you want to download a file from Azure data lake Gen2 with a service principal, we need to grant the security principal read access to the file and give the security principal Execute permissions to the container and each folder in the hierarchy of folders that lead to the file. Regarding how to configure it, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control).

2. Script

```
$AppID  = "" 
$AccessKeyValue  = ""
$TenantId=""


$azurePassword    = ConvertTo-SecureString $AccessKeyValue -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred           = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AppID, $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $TenantId


$AzureDataLakeAccountName  = ""
$ctx =New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $AzureDataLakeAccountName -UseConnectedAccount 

$filesystemName="<your container name>"
$path="<your blob name>"
$LocalTargetFilePathName  = ""
Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $path -Destination $LocalTargetFilePathName
```

Comment: Hi Jim, I realized that Export-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem works only for ADL Gen1. It does not work for ADL Gen2 (blob files). We need to use the command "Get-AzureStorageBlobContent"

Comment: I tried using below command :                                                                                                         Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "/Test/Partner/Account/" -Blob "Account.parquet" -Destination "D:\MoveToModern"                                                                                                            But I was getting an error Could not get the storage context.  Please pass in a storage context or set the current storage context.     Do you have any idea on this

Comment: Thanks Jim. It woked